# C Case in loop problems

Tags: c

I have multiple errors with this project. The first and most important one would have to be one I answer a question in a case. Rather than it going back to choosing a case, it instead goes towards the difficulty. This won't let me exit the program and to get the average questions correct.

Another error is the end average questions correct. My program crashes whenever I try to just skip questions and go to the end. All it would do is divide 0/0 unless that's not possible. I'm supposed to use a switch function which is something I've seen has a problem with loops. Sadly, I can't find a way to fix it on my end, or every answer has just gone right over my head.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int option = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    int ttlProblems = 0;
    int correctAnswers = 0;
    double averageCorrect = 0;
    char difficulty;

    printf("Math Practice Program Menu");

    printf("\n\n1. Addition\n");
    printf("2. Subtraction \n");
    printf("3. Multiplication \n");
    printf("4. Division \n");
    printf("5. Exit\n\n");

    printf("Select an option: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &option);

    while (option != 5)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Select difficulty level...\ne for easy\nm for medium\nh for hard\n");
            scanf_s(" %c", &difficulty, 1);
            if (difficulty == 'e')
            {
                printf("3 + 1 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 4)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'm')
            {
                printf("34 + 19 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 53)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'h')
            {
                printf("134 + 119 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 253)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                printf("Invalid difficulty set\n");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Select difficulty level...\ne for easy\nm for medium\nh for hard\n");
            scanf_s(" %c", &difficulty, 1);


            if (difficulty == 'e')
            {
                printf("3 - 1 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 2)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'm')
            {
                printf("34 - 19 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 15)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'h')
            {
                printf("134 - 119 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 15)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                printf("Invalid difficulty s\n");
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Select difficulty level...\ne for easy\nm for medium\nh for hard\n");
            scanf_s(" %c", &difficulty, 1);


            if (difficulty == 'e')
            {
                printf("3 * 1 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 3)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'm')
            {
                printf("34 * 19 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 646)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'h')
            {
                printf("134 * 119 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);

                if (answer == 15946)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                printf("Invalid difficulty set\n");
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("Select difficulty level...\ne for easy\nm for medium\nh for hard\n");
            scanf_s(" %c", &difficulty, 1);

            if (difficulty == 'e')
            {
                printf("9 / 2 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);
                printf("Enter any remainder: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &remainder, 1);

                if (answer == 4 && remainder == 1)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'm')
            {
                printf("34 / 19 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);
                printf("Enter any remainder: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &remainder, 1);

                if (answer == 1 && remainder == 15)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else if (difficulty == 'h')
            {
                printf("134 / 19 = ? Enter answer: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &answer, 1);
                printf("Enter any remainder: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &remainder, 1);

                if (answer == 7 && remainder == 1)
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    ++correctAnswers;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++ttlProblems;
                    printf("Sorry, Incorrect\n");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                printf("Invalid difficulty set\n");
                break;
            }
            break;

        case 5:
            break;

        default:
            printf("Not a valid option.\n");
        }
    }
    averageCorrect = ttlProblems / correctAnswers;
    printf("You attempted %d problems and got %d correct\nFor a percentage of %.2f correct.", ttlProblems, correctAnswers, averageCorrect);
}
```

Comment: I didn't read through your entire code, because it is very long, but dividing 0 by 0 will definitely crash a C program (and most other languages, too).

Comment: Ah okay. So I can only exit is there is 1 question. A lot of the code is repeated. It pretty much asks what type of question I want, then asks for a difficulty, then gives the question and asks for an answer.  I just need to understand why it's repeating the difficulty and not the type of question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code asks the user to enter the option type before the while loop, so it will only ask once and use that value for the option every loop iteration. Moving your option input `scanf_s("%d", &option);` into the beginning of the while loop should solve your first problem.

In regards to dividing by zero, this will cause the program to crash because it is not possble. You might want to check whether `correctAnswers` is zero or not before performing the division.

Comment: Would I just have to put in an if statement at the end if no questions were asked? I feel like that would quickly solve the crashing problem.

Comment: One more question. Since I'm running a while loop, it ends up asking for an option twice before it moves on. I know that a for loop would run the body first which is technically what I need, I just don't know how I'd apply it here since I've only used for loops with counters.

Comment: It's do while loops that execute the body before check the loop condition. This would look something like this: `do { ... } while (option != 5);`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!